# JSON definition - data structure or data format?

Tags: json

What is more correct? Say that JSON is a **data structure** or a **data format**?

Comment: Not a coding question... ... .. ..

Comment: @FlashThunder you are right. What is the best StackExchange site to put this type of questions?

Comment: not sure maybe data science ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly ambiguous and depends on your interpration of the words.

The way I see it:
A datastructure, in conventional Comp Sci / Programming i.e. array, queue, binary tree usually has a specific purpose. Json can be pretty much be used for anything, hence why it's a data-format. But both definitions make sense

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion both is correct.

JSON is also a data format (.json) and also a data strucuture which you can use for instance in Java etc.

But more correct is data strucutre.

Comment: I agree with this completely. I'd like to point out that http://www.json.org/ defines JSON as "a lightweight data-interchange format."

Answer (score 1):

> JSON (canonically pronounced /ˈdʒeɪsən/ jay-sən;[1] sometimes
>   JavaScript Object Notation) is an open-standard format that uses
>   human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of
>   attribute–value pairs. It is the most common **data format** used for
>   asynchronous browser/server communication (AJAJ), largely replacing
>   XML which is used by AJAX.

Source: Wikipedia